# Текущее положение в Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Android Studio, Google Maps, что прописать в коде, чтобы текущее положение всегда отображалось в центре экрана?

А то получается карта неподвижна, а точка с онлайн положением уехала за край видимой области.

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом при получении новой `Location` извлеките из неё долготу и широту и соберите `LatLng` объект. Затем создайте объект

`CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng);`

И примените его к карте `mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cu)` это без анимации или `.animateCamera(cu)` если хотите с анимацией. Все эти операции проделывать при каждом обновлении локации. Тогда ваша точка всегда будет по центру экрана

Подробнее про это читайте в [документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views)

Comment: Спасибо!!! Этот метод я и использовал mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cu), брал пример у google, положение он показывает точно, стандартная метка с текущ положением смещается при движении, а вот сама карта "стоит" на месте, и метка уходит за пределы экрана. Может нужно в другое место поставить mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cu)?

Comment: у вас есть коллбек куда падает новая локация. туда суньте обновление камеры